# Joomla 3 module to show latest weblinks

Tags: joomla

I've copied for this purpose the mod_articles_latest, and changed all naming from 'articles' to 'weblinks' etc. Module works, but except for one issue. The module shows the latest weblinks from all categories, and when I want to make a selection from one or more categories, it continues to display weblinks from all categories. I tried some changes in helper.php around this code:

```
// Category filter
$model->setState('filter.category_id', $params->get('catid', array()));
```

But I didn't succeed. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

You should not change anything in the source as far as code goes. Undo everything you did and create new language files. You should change all the Language Strings **not** the code.

Language string look like this:
`JText::_("MODULE_NAME_SOMETHING");`

Comment: I've not changed anything in the core, I've 'cloned' the core-module, renamed/changed everything to 'latest weblinks' and now trying to optimize the cloned module. The problem can't be solved in the language files, it has to be solved in the filtering-code for the categories.